# How can I design database for following requirements?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, database-design, database-connection

I need help in Database Designing.

Project Description:

1. I am developing a GRE Vocabulary App, in which there are five pages(All Word List, Favourite Word, Confusing Word, Common Word, Word by Category).
2. All word list contains the whole word available. For eg. List contains 1000 Words.
3. Favorite list contains the word chosen from All words by the user. For eg. 200 words from the list of 1000 words.
4. Confusing word compares two many as required words from All word list by Admin. For eg. Strive vs Strife, these two words are also in list of 1000 words.
5. Common words contain words, from All word lists by Admin. for eg. Immaculate, Happy, etc.
6. Word by category contains words list from All words which are classified by their category. For eg. "Happy" category contains Elation, Ecstasy, Joy, Pleasure, Delight, etc.

Comment: Please ask exactly 1 specific non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Please don't ask us to do your (home)work. What parts are you able to do? What did your textbook or the documentation say about anything relevant? "I need help" is not a question. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this to be a single-user app? Or multiple users accessing the same database? It is important for item 3. In which case, what else do you need for managing "users". And is the "Admin" a form of 'super' user who can do certain maintenance actions that users cannot do?

Can one word be in multiple categories? That is, do you need many:many or 1:many mapping? The former needs an extra table.

Let me get you started by providing a way to think about this problem (and a large class of Database design problems):

List the "entities" you have:

- Words -- the word, whether 'common', etc.
- Categories
- Confusables -- maybe this works like Categories?
- Users

List the "relationships":

- Word : Category
- User : favorite word

Comment: What is mean by Single User and Multi-User? There are 400 students who use this application and one admin who added the words and manage their meanings. As I mentioned in the question, Confused words and Categories are different. In confusing words, there are a list of words where two are similar in looks but have a different meaning, for example, "Strive and Strife, Contrite and Contrive"

Comment: @SunilTimilsina - Each of the 400 "users" has his own list of "favorite words" but not a separate list of "confusing word"?  That is, the design will need `user_id` in some tables, but not others.

Comment: Yeah, only favorite words are different for different users. Confusing words, Categories are similar for all the users.